# I want to generate the hyperlink for all figure callout in the text and id should be same as figure id

Tags: xslt

Please check and suggest, 
what should be the right code and idref value should be same as figure id. I am trying with analyze-string but unable to do.

Please check and suggest, 
what should be the right code and idref value should be same as figure id. I am trying with analyze-string but unable to do.

**input**

```
<book>
    <figure id="ch01fig01">
        <label>Figure 01</label>
        <figcaption>xxx</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>This is a Figure 01 and this is figure 02</p>
    <p>This is a Figure 01 and this is figure 02</p>
    <figure id="ch01fig02">
        <label>Figure 02</label>
        <figcaption>xxx</figcaption>
    </figure>
</book>
```

**output**

```
    <book>
    <figure id="ch01fig01">
        <label>Figure 01</label>
        <figcaption>xxx</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>This is a <internal idref="ch01fig01">Figure 01</internal> and this is <internal idref="ch01fig02">Figure 02</internal></p>
    <p>This is a <internal idref="ch01fig01">Figure 01</internal> and this is <internal idref="ch01fig02">Figure 02</internal></p>
   <figure id="ch01fig02">
        <label>Figure 02</label>
        <figcaption>xxx</figcaption>
    </figure>

</book>
```

**xslt**

```
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//text()[not(parent::label)]">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="figure\s+\d+" flags="i">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <internal>
                    <xsl:attribute name="idref">
                        <xsl:call-template name="mk">
                            <xsl:with-param name="mk11" select="."/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </internal>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="mk">
        <xsl:param name="mk11"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="//figure">
            <xsl:if test="child::label eq $mk11">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>    
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

First consider using a key to look up the figures...

```
<xsl:key name="figures" match="figure" use="lower-case(label)" />
```

(I am using lower-case here, because you have a "figure 02" in the text, but "Figure 02" in the label).

Your main problem is that within `xsl:matching-substring` you are no longer within the context of the original node you are matching, so you are probably getting an error along the lines of "the context item is not a node"

To get around this, define a variable to allow you to reference the original document...

```
<xsl:variable name="doc" select="/" />
```

Then to get the figure value using the key, you can do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('figures', lower-case($mk11), $doc)/@id" />
```

So, this will look up the key in the context of the original document.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="figures" match="figure" use="lower-case(label)" />
   <xsl:variable name="doc" select="/" />

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//text()[not(parent::label)]">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="figure\s+\d+" flags="i">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <internal>
                    <xsl:attribute name="idref">
                        <xsl:call-template name="mk">
                            <xsl:with-param name="mk11" select="."/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </internal>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="mk">
        <xsl:param name="mk11"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('figures', lower-case($mk11), $doc)/@id" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In fact, you can simplify this by doing away with the named template, and making use of Attribute Value Templates to create the `idref` attribute

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="figures" match="figure" use="lower-case(label)" />
   <xsl:variable name="doc" select="/" />

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//text()[not(parent::label)]">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="figure\s+\d+" flags="i">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <internal idref="{key('figures', lower-case(.), $doc)/@id}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </internal>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But you get bonus points for using XSLT 3.0 and demonstrating the use of Text Value Templates too!

Answer (score 2):

**I used another way instead of the key as well it is also working good. Below is code done some changes.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="figs" select="//figure" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[not(parent::label)]">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="matches(., 'Figure', 'i')">
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(Figure ([0-9]+))" flags="i">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:variable name="ids" select="for $ss in $figs
                            return 
                            if(matches($ss/label, regex-group(1), 'i'))
                            then $ss/@id
                            else ()"></xsl:variable>
                        <internal idref="{$ids[1]}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </internal>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Below is the outcome after running XSLT.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <figure id="ch01fig01">
        <label>Figure 01</label>
        <figcaption>xxx</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <p>This is a <internal idref="ch01fig01">Figure 01</internal> and this is <internal idref="ch01fig02">figure 02</internal>
   </p>
    <p>This is a <internal idref="ch01fig01">Figure 01</internal> and this is <internal idref="ch01fig02">figure 02</internal>
   </p>
    <figure id="ch01fig02">
        <label>Figure 02</label>
        <figcaption>xxx</figcaption>
    </figure>
</book>
```